# Proper way to connect two 8 gauge wires in junction box?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I need to connect two 8/3 wires together in a junction box. What is the correct type of connector to do this? The two hardware stores I went to had nothing for 8 gauge wires.

Answer (score 4):

You mean 8/3 cables, which are going to have four individual wires in need of splicing.

You can use extra-large wire nuts for the job.

Another option is the ILSCO "MAC Block Connector".  This is a lug connector, larger than an Alumiconn, far cheaper than a Polaris.  Hard to find, but some box stores and many electrical supply houses will have it.  (To google it you need to say "Ilsco" or "connector"... the term "mac block" gives nothing useful.)

Also the MAC Block is aluminum rated, so if the other end of either run is rated for aluminum also (like breakers are), you could use #6Al for that side of the run, and save some money on wire.

Comment: We don't _know_ that OP meant cables. You might expound on the nut portion in case it actually is just two wires.

Answer (score 0):

[Insulated 2 Conductor Splice Connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005FMQ5UW)

These are big connectors so space in the box get get tight but they are made for 4-14 AWG wires. They come in different sizes and orientations. Links to Amazon and I ordered these for a 50amp hot tub installation